# Is there any cli to detect directory changes between bash script runs?

Tags: bash, filesystems, cache

For example I have this command

```bash
generate-and-deploy-new-version ./site-directory
```

and I want to run it only if content of the `./site-directory` was changed.

```bash
if checkchanges "./site-directory" ; then
  generate-and-deploy-new-version ./site-directory
fi
```

`checkchanges` could generate some hash of the directory content, save it in file and check it next time it will run.

Comment: Do you want to run it every time it's updated, or periodic?

Comment: Integrity checking is relatively expensive and becomes more expensive that larger your deployment becomes so the common approach is to  assume that the current version was deployed correctly and hasn't been modified/damaged since deployment ==> then checking for a version string should enough. You then apply some logic `installed_version != latest ; install latest` and  `if force-reinstalll == yes ; install latest`

Comment: @vidarlo I want to run it periodically.